# How to convert an existing ASP.NET project into MVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a ASP.NET project which calls a DAL class I wrote, to retrieve data to display on the page, most of the heavy lifting is in the DAL class.

As you can see, it pretty straightforward, although I do have some minor validation code in my aspx page.

Question here is that: how can I convert this project into a MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [NerdDinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm), and understand the patterns first, before attempting to do a conversion.

There really isn't an automated way of doing it, AFAIK.  There are too many moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a large project you are converting it may pay to integrate MVC into your existing Web Application and converting bit by bit.

We're in the process of doing that and it seems to be working quite well.

Comment: What was your reasoning for performing the conversion?  We are developing an MVC site right now, but some of our devs still long for the webforms style.